# What's the best way to synchronize geographically diverse mysql servers?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, redis, database

Imaging that I have a number of servers which all run mysql or mongodb or redis database, 
the servers are in different places. I want to keep the server's data all the same.

for example:

```
server A,B,C,D,E 
1> insert items to A, auto update B,C,D,E
2> insert items to B, auto update A,C,D,E
3> delete ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is rather generic but the answer in all cases is a similar starting point for syncing the same data to multiple servers:

- MySQL - [use replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html)
- MongoDB - [use replication](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replication)
- redis - [use replication](http://redis.io/topics/replication)

Depending on the database, you may have limitations such as whether replication is single master (all of the above generally are, out of the box) or whether you truly need multi-master updates (eg. [MySQL Cluster](http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/), [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org), or other database with [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control)).

There are pros and cons of different approaches, and it really depends on your use case and where the servers are in relation to each other (same data centre, geographically diverse, etc).  Generally you would want to scale up to the appropriate scenario rather than trying to start out with something overly complex to set up and support.